# How to check if an item has expired or not using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a form that is used for renewing policies that have been bought by a person.

My idea of this is that, the expiry date of the item to be renewed should be  checked
against the new date of purchase from the renewal form.

I have tried this out:

```
$check="SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE Expiry_Date > '$_POST[newDate]' and Policy_Number = '$_POST[Policy_Number]' ";
```

But it doesn't do a correct check.

Instead e.g if the expiry date was "2015-23-9" and the newDate was "2015-22-9", it still accepts data which is not supposed to be, but if the new date was e.g "2014-22-19" it would then give the derived result I was looking for.

How does one do a check against an item(policy_number) and its expiry date using the new date to see if the item was truly expired or not as regards to my sql statement?

Comment: what is the data type of "Expiry_Date" in your table?

Comment: the data type is text

Comment: i have used a hidden field to get my start date and expiry date based on the present date with this <?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>

Comment: In your sql statement you are comparing dates. However, you are comparing the date string with a text field which will not give you the correct answer. To do date comparisons in SQL, you have to have the column as either DATETIME or TIMESTAMP data type.

Comment: ok let me change that, i left that in text because i had to get that manually

Comment: Comparing dates available here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216076/oracle-sql-comparing-dates

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using a format like this to store dates: YYYY-DD-M  It seems like they are stored that way in your column and presented that way to the DBMS in your query.

Dates stored that way won't collate -- compare to each other -- correctly.

Try this in your SQL

```
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Expiry_Date, '%Y-%d-%m') >
                         STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[newDate]' , '%Y-%d-%m')
```

The formatting string `'%Y-%d-%m'` tells `STR_TO_DATE()` that your strings are in your YYYY-DD-M format.  If you give this function a bogus date like `2014-22-19` it will return NULL, so be careful.

This will convert both your input and your column values to `DATE` fields, which compare the way you'd expect.

Better yet, if you can, switch to using YYYY-MM-DD string formatting for your dates, and to using the `DATE` datatype  in your column. You'll love that because you'll be able to speed things up with an index.